# Win10でのVSCodeを使いRaspberry Pi PicoをPythonの作り方

Tags: python, windows, vscode, raspberry-pi

Win10でVSCodeを使いRaspberry Pi PicoをPythonでプログラムしたいです。
以下のページを参考にしています。

[VS CodeからRaspberry Pi Picoを動かす](https://hobby.houja.net/2021/05/01/310/)

このページの「●Pico-Stubの追加、こちらからzip・・・」にある"micropy"がどこにあるコマンドかわかりません。

またサンプル(LEDを光らせるだけ)で作ったコードでは以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
例外が発生しました: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'machine'
```

どうすればいいかわかりません。教えてください。

追記１→解決しました
コメントをいただき、参考にしてるサイト「遊び小屋」に書かれている内容を進めて行きました。
micropy initの「Autocomp と Pylint を 選択後・・・」の項で

> MicroPy You don't have any stubs!
> MicroPy To add stubs to micropy, use micropy stubs add <STUB_NAME>

google翻訳によると "スタブを追加して" という内容でした。

追記２
以下が動かそうとしているソースです。

```
from machine import Pin
import time

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)

while True:
    time.sleep(1.0) #1秒待機
    led.value(1)

    time.sleep(1.0) #1秒待機
    led.value(0)
```

このコードで、
1行目: Missing module docstringpylint(missing-module-docstring)
1行目: Unable to import 'machine'pylint(import-error)
2行目: standard import "import time" should be placed before "from machine import Pin"pylint(wrong-import-order)
というエラーが出ています。
エラーの内容を説明できる程のスキルは当方にはありません。
お力添えお願いします。

追記３
oririさん、ありがとうございます。
すごく助かります、ネットで見るみなさんのページが今のRaspberryPiのサイトとデザイが違っていてここでいいの？ という感じでした。
また、microPythonがどんな形で(Pythonの一部か別のセットか)わかっていなかったのでダウンロード先がわかったことは嬉しいです。
https://micropython.org/download/
ただ、依然としてVSCodeでmicroPythonのPathが解決していません。
OSの環境変数以外のPython、VSCodeでのPathの通し方がわかりません。

Comment: VSCodeは情報無さそうですが、検索でこんな記事が見つかるので、調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [初めの一歩！ラズパイPicoマイコン×PythonでLチカ入門開発環境のセットアップから点灯/消灯制御プログラミングまで](https://www.marutsu.co.jp/pc/static/large_order/zep/m-z-picoled-da1), [技術コラム（第24回）Raspberry Pi PicoのPythonを使う](https://www.kumikomi-kaihatu.com/technical-column/column-024/), [PicoでとりあえずMicroPythonを動かしてみる](https://blog.boochow.com/article/rpi-pico-upython.html)

Comment: `"micropy"がどこにあるコマンドか`ということであれば、そのページのその上に書いてある`pip install micropy-cli`でインストールしたものでしょう。[Micropy Cli](https://micropy-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) pythonが使える環境のコマンドプロンプトで該当部分の処理を行えば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 参考にしてるサイト「遊び小屋」に書かれいる内容を進めて行きました。micropy initの「Autocomp と Pylint を 選択後・・・」の項で”MicroPy  You don't have any stubs!
MicroPy  To add stubs to micropy, use micropy stubs add <STUB_NAME>
”(スタブを追加して)と言われました。報告です。

Comment: そうした詳しい/変化した状況は、コメントに書くのではなく質問内容を編集して追記するかまとめて書き直すかして、質問記事だけで内容が完結するようにしてください。何か複数の環境があって、VSCodeで使っているものが間違った環境を選んでいるとかなのでは？

Comment: ちなみにその系統の別の記事がこちらになると思われます。[【初見にオススメ】Raspberry Pi PicoをブラウザだけでLチカする入門 (Web Serial API)](https://qiita.com/n0bisuke/items/c16f77c7017a2d4018dd), [Raspberry Pi PicoにThonnyじゃなくてVS Codeでコードを流し込んでみる](https://qiita.com/n0bisuke/items/5fb2f1592c7bfd804015), [ラズパイPicoでLチカ（３）VS Code + Pico-Go で入力補完あり 1/2](https://qiita.com/naohiro2g/items/bdaeac218f83de2d3c5b), [Pico(Visual Studio Code)Windows環境設定(Python言語)](https://shinog.jp/computer/raspberry-pi/picovisual-studio-codewindows%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9Apython%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E/)

Comment: 質問から読み取れる状況は「わからない」, だけなので回答付きにくいかと思います。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) などあるので目を通しておくとよいかも。記したほうがよいと思える 現在の状況として, Picoのセットアップはどこまで完了しているのか (ファームウェアは書き込んだのか, Pico動作確認は終わっているのか, PCと接続しているのか, など)。Pico用の開発環境(IDE)としては何と何と何をインストールしセットアップが終わってるのか等, これらを質問に追記したほうがよいかも

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
自分はずっとVSCodeのメニューバーにある「実行(R)」にある「デバックの開始」で実行と思っていました。
正しくは「コマンドパレット(Ctrl+Shift+P)」からたどれる「Pico-Go」の"Run current file"コマンド？だとわかりました。
とりあえずこのスレッドは解決としてします。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

現状が不明なので記して欲しい旨 コメントしたけど, 反応がない

質問は, IDEセットアップで躓いてる点の解決を望んでるようだけど
この回答は, その点ではなく, **(事前に行うはずの) Picoのセットアップ**について, です
(反応がないのは, Picoセットアップ行っていないなどで, 用語が伝わっていない可能性がある ため)

---

#### ● Microcontrollers について

本家のサイト raspberrypi.com, その中の該当しそうなページ

- [Microcontrollers](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/)

  - [RP2040](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/rp2040.html)
  - [Raspberry Pi Pico and Pico W](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/raspberry-pi-pico.html)
  - [MicroPython](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/micropython.html)
  - [The C/C++ SDK](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/c_sdk.html)

(取説か何かに この辺りは記されているかと思うが, 念の為)

PC, あるいは Raspberry Pi などとは異なり, Raspberry Pi **Pico系統**はマイコン (Microcontroller) と呼ばれています

- 消費電力が少ない, RAMも少ない

- OSは載らない (Real-time OSなら乗るかもしれないが, 汎用のは制限が厳しくムリ)
- (Arduinoなどもこの類)

##### ● Firmware

汎用的な OSは搭載ムリなので, パワーオンと同時に予め書き込んでおいたプログラムが起動する, ことになる

MicroPythonは主に Microcontrollersをターゲットとした言語処理系で, firmware (ファームウェア)に書き込んでおき, パワーオンと同時に起動することになる
参考: firmware 単語検索 (https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=firmware)

(PCなどでは, ディスクから RAMへプログラムをロードし 制御を渡す。
MicroPython (本体)は firmwareから直接起動する, ことが多い)

Firmware書き込み手順は, 上記 URLの 「MicroPython」参照

- Picoの BOOTSEL ボタン押しながら USB接続
- Drag and drop (あるいは代替手段)で MicroPython UF2 ファイルを指定
- 正常に書き込めたことの確認に, REPL (Read-Eval-Print Loop) で動作確認するとよい

##### ● MicroPython

[MicroPython ドキュメンテーション](https://micropython-docs-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/)

- [MicroPythonとCPythonの違い](https://micropython-docs-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/genrst/index.html)
- プラットフォーム固有のリファレンスとチュートリアル:

  - [RP2 用クイックリファレンス](https://micropython-docs-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/rp2/quickref.html)
  - その他: pyboard 用, ESP32 用など

MicroPython は CPython に似せてあるはずだが, 土俵が違うので相違点はそれなりにある
また, プラットフォーム毎にもそれぞれ違いがある

四則演算程度ならば 同じように記述できるが
`import micropython` とか(あるいはその他) CPythonでは当然動かない
`import rp2` などの部分は, Pico以外では動かない
統合開発環境 (IDE) での実行は, REPL 経由のはず (デスクトップ PCの CPythonでは当然動かないので)